# Big numbers regex

Tags: php

```
$value = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", '', $value);
```

How could I edit this regex to get rid of everything after the decimal point? There may or may not be a decimal point.

Currently "100.1" becomes 1001 but it should be 100.

Complete function:

```
   function intfix($value)
    {
        $value = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", '', $value);
        $value = trim($value);
        return $value + 0;
    }
```

It is used to format user input for numbers as well as servers output to format numbers for the DB. The functions deals with very large numbers, so I can't use intval or similar. Any extra comments to improve this function are welcome.

Comment: What if use `strstr` with **.** or **,** as `$needle` and `$before_needle` as true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change the regex to `/[^0-9].*/s`.

`.*` matches zero or more characters, so the first character that is not a digit, and the digits that immediately follow, would be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a pattern that starts the search with a decimal place. At the moment you're only deleting the `.` not the numbers after it... So you could do `'/\.[\d]+/'`

```
$text = "1201.21 12 .12  12.21";
$text = preg_replace('/\.[\d]+/', '' ,$text);
```

The above code would result in `$text = "1201 12 12"`

Answer (score 0):

Why not `$value = round($value, 0);`?  This can handle large values and is meant to get rid of the following decimals mathematically (I'd rather work with numbers as numbers not as strings).  You can pass `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` as a third parameter if you want to just get rid of the decimals `10.7` -> `10`. Or `floor($value);` could work too.

Comment: I read the question as "how to round an integer greater than 2^53 or 2^63 - 1 toward zero, and get an exact answer".